# The chart duplicates the values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to make a visual presentation of filtered data. So the same data are shown in the table and also the chart. In the table, we can see the original data, but when I put it in the chart, this data is actually doubled compared to the original.

[image]

Can anybody help me solve this problem and have the same chart as the data in the table? Below you can see how the graph is set.

[image]

Also, you can see that the numbers are not summarized

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried to remove SUM, but it is no option for that. Also, if I remove Year there is no option for making of a chart without Year. The final result is to have Values and Year on X-axis and Y-axis.

Comment: Use don't summarize feature

Comment: You can see the post above again. I updated. Values are not summarized

Comment: But in chart, it is showing Sum of value

Comment: Yes, I also ask why it appears? Summarization does not occur in the table, but it does in the chart

Comment: Because you already Don't summarize value in column tools

Answer (score 0):

Remove SUM aggregation in Y axis and FirstDayOfYear from X axis.
Use Don't Summarize

Comment: if issue got resolved then accept answer and upvote